# Cannot scrape google patent URL through python and Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, google-patent-search

I am currently trying to scrape a link to Google Patents on this page,
https://datatool.patentsview.org/#detail/patent/10745438, but when I am trying to print out all of the links with an 'a' tag, only an unrelated website comes up.

Here is my code so far:

```
url = 'https://datatool.patentsview.org/#detail/patent/10745438'
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')

links = []
print(soup)
for link in soup.find_all('a', href=True):
    print(link['href'])
```

When I print out the soup, the 'a' tag with the link to the google patents isn't printed, nor is the link in the array. The only thing printed is

```
http://uspto.gov/
tel:1-800-786-9199
./#viz/relationships
./#viz/locations
./#viz/comparisons
```

, which is all unnecessary information. Is google protecting their links in some way, or is there any other way I can retrieve the link to the google patent or redirect to the page?

Comment: It looks like the links are being protected. If you select `inspect-element` (on the webpage), you'll notice that the links come inside `div class="overlay"`, which doesn't appear in the parsed soup.

Comment: Is there anyway to access the link even though it's protected?

Comment: I see you're trying to print out all the a hrefs there are, but is there a specific link are area of links you're truly trying to capture within that page (an I'm assuming similar pages)?

Comment: @pedwards Yes, I am trying to get the link that redirects to the google patent, specifically, https://www.google.com/patents/US10745438, in this case. The text states "go to google patent" as the hyperlink.

Comment: I was trying to install a package that looked very interesting to me that would perform the function you're trying for.  For some reason I was having troubles installing it.  But take a look at the requests_html python package.  I think it would do exactly what you want.  https://pypi.org/project/requests-html/

Comment: Another option I was coming across was a package named Selenium, which was recommended by a couple others.  Both these packages allow the pages to fully load prior to scraping.

Answer (score 1):

Don't scrape it, just do some link hacking:

```
url = 'https://datatool.patentsview.org/#detail/patent/10745438'
google_patents_url = 'https://www.google.com/patents/US' + url.rsplit('/', 1)[1]
```

Comment: Wonderful workaround. But, how did you know this though? Was there any specific documentation/API?

Comment: No, I just recognized that the numbers were the same in both links. Apparently this is the patent number, which allows for some convenient link hacking.